# ¿Por qué pone continuamente error de rango?

Tags: fortran

```
program liga

    implicit none

        integer:: i,j,suma
        integer, parameter:: N = 4, M = 20
        real:: A(N,M), p(M),u

        u=(/3.0,1.0,0.0/)


        open (UNIT=8, FILE='partidos.dat')
        open (UNIT=9, FILE= 'puntos.dat')


        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)

            do i= 2,N

            read (8,*) A(i,j) 

            end do 

            do i=1,N

              suma=0.0 

               do j= 1,3 

                suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u)
                p(M) = suma                

               end do 

               p(M)=suma

            end do 

       write (9,*) 
       write (9,*) 'Puntos de los equipos'
       write (9,*)

       write (9,*) p(j)


end program
```

Hay un error al intentar compilar el programa, estoy intentando cambiar las dimensiones pero da errores continuamente.

```
u=(/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
```

> Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Answer (score 0):

```
real:: A(N,M), p(M),u

u=(/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
```

`u` no está declarada como un array.

```
integer, parameter:: N = 4, M = 20, H = 3
real:: A(N,M), p(M),u(H)

u=(/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado, pero ahora sale otro "   suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u)"

Comment: Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Comment: @Joaquin Si `u` es un array no puedes usarlo en una operación sin su correspondiente índice... ¿Cómo resolverías tu `a=5+{3,4,5}`?

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien. No se como ponerlo en el código.

Comment: @Joaquin eso es porque, como te he remarcado ya tres veces, no tienes nada claro ni lo que tienes que hacer ni cómo puedes hacerlo. Mirando tu código por encima... si estás iterando `j` de 1 a 3, siendo `3` la dimensión de `u`, a mí se me ocurriría probar `suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))`

Comment: Muchas gracias.